# After upgrading from PHP 5.3.8 to 5.3.20, started receiving Cannot redeclare class errors

Tags: php

I recently upgraded to PHP 5.3.8 to 5.3.20.  Once the upgrade was in place, I started receiving numerous **Cannot redeclare** errors:

> [20-Dec-2012 11:15:00 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class user in /var/www/htdocs/includes/mysql.php on line 3

In one of my PHP classes, I instantiate a mysql class in a constructor using code like:

```
class foo {
  function foo() {  
    global $db;

    require '/var/www/htdocs/includes/mySQL.php';
    $db = new mydb_driver();
  }

  function show_text() {
    require '/var/www/htdocs/includes/mySQL.php';
    $db2 = new mydb_driver();
  }
}
```

In the same class, I create a function that instantiates the same mysql class using a different variable so I can connect to a different database.  This second require is what is triggering the errors and I am unsure why. If I remove the require from show_text or change it to require_once it works fine.

Does anyone know what changed between these two versions that would cause this code to fail?  I am not even sure how $db2 is being properly intialized without the require. Does requiring the class constructor make it globally visible in the file?

**Edit:**
This is not a logging issue and the errors were not happening before the upgrade.  The apps were working fine until the upgrade.  This how I have enabled errors in my error logging:

```
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: You also got those errors on your previous PHP version. It's just that you only now have errors enabled.

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't such an error _before_ the upgrade? I don't think so.

Comment: My php.ini is exactly the same and I was receiving no errors.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, but this is not a logging issue.  Errors were being logged in my PHP errorlog before I upgraded. Also the apps themselves that started throwing the error were working perfectly before I upgraded and only stopped after the upgrade when this error started appearing. I  have updated my initial question with my php.ini config where i have errors enabled.

Comment: fatal errors wouldve caused the script to crash before anyways... regardless of error reporting no?

Comment: @Ascherer Exactly, which is why none of this makes sense to me.

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
require_once '/var/www/htdocs/includes/mySQL.php';

class foo {
  function foo() {  
    global $db;

    $db = new mydb_driver();
  }

  function show_text() {
    $db2 = new mydb_driver();
  }
}
```

Requires belong at the top of the file, and although slower, `require_once` will prevent the file from being required twice, giving you that error

can't really assume to know what you are trying to do. But you could switch it to something like this too, to get rid of globals and confine more to the PSR standards

```
require_once '/var/www/htdocs/includes/mySQL.php';

class foo {
  private $db;

  public function __construct( )
  {
      $this->db = new mydb_driver();
  }
  public function bar() {  
      // Do bar stuff with $this->db
  }

  public function show_text() {
      // Doo show_text stuff with $this->db
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Still not sure why this happened, but this helps to define how I should be including my files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In you class, change `require` to `require_once`. This ensures that file is loaded at most once.

Comment: Wasn't the file, though, only being included in the constructor scope?  Why was it then visible to the show_text function as already included ?

Comment: there is no constructor scope in your example

Comment: @Ascherer In my example above, isn't function foo() the constructor? From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php "For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics. "

Comment: i did not know that... hmm. Learn something new every day. but either way, the require adds to the global scope, not the class scope

Answer (score 2):

You also got those errors on your previous PHP version. It's just that you only now have errors enabled (which is something you should always do in a development environment). You can only "load" the class once. When you are going to deploy it to the product environment you should still have errors enabled, but only log them instead of displaying them.

To enable error reporting you can do:

```
error_reporting(-1); // or you could do `E_ALL` in PHP 5.4
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Also you should stop using the `global` keyword. It is bad practice because you make it impossible to test your code, introduce tight coupling and may introduce unpredictable results.

```
class foo {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function foo() {  
        $this->db->doSomething();
    }

    public function show_text() {
        $this->db->doSomething();
    }
}

require '/var/www/htdocs/includes/mySQL.php';
$db = new Mydb_driver();
$foo = new Foo($db);
```

*Note: that I have also added the visibility to your methods (`public`). Although they are public by default it is always better to add it so people would not think it is a mistake.*

You may also want to read into [autoloading your classes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)/ This prevent you from doing `require_*`, `include_*` and friends so it helps keeping your code clean, prevent errors when forgetting to load classes and would also prevent errors like you got now.

Comment: He also can use `require_once` to make sure the class is loaded just once.

Comment: @EmCo Sure he can. I never said he couldn't. It's just that the only `require_*`, `include_*` one needs in some code would be the one to require the autoloader.

Comment: @PeeHaa unfortunately, an autoloader can be hard to implement on a project that is already completed without one

Comment: @Ascherer depends. If OP has done a lot of those double requires he/she might as well get rid of all of them and implement an autoloader, because OP would need to go through them either way. But in general you are right. P.S. tnx for edit :)

Comment: could just do a find sed to replace them all :)